# TypeORM how to seed database

Tags: typeorm

I am running my Node JS backend using typeorm ORM.

Coming from Entity Framework, it was very easy to seed the db with a few lines such as

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DbInitializer());
```

Where the DbInitializer class would contain all the seeding info.

Is there a similar approach to seed the database in TypeOrm?
If not, what is the recommended way of doing it?

1) Create a new migration with the data insertion statements?
2) Create a task where you instantiate and save entities?

Comment: Seed a database?  You can enter data directly through some GUI or command line SQL code or just build your CRUD modules and enter data.

Comment: using typeorm cli you can create migrations, as described at https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md

Comment: i recently published an article on how you can seed DB. Please check it out: 
https://medium.com/@bansalsushil_34403/how-to-seed-typeorm-d9637a5948cc

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would love to see such functionality as well (and [we're not alone](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1305)), but [at the](https://github.com/w3tecch/express-typescript-boilerplate/issues/56) [moment](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1763), there's no official feature for seeding.

in lack of such a built-in feature, I think the next best thing would be to create a migration script named `0-Seed` (so it precedes any other migration scripts you might have) and have the seed data populated there.

[@bitwit](https://github.com/bitwit) has created [a snippet](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1550#issuecomment-381039669) that may come in handy for you; it's a function that reads the data from yaml files, which you can incorporate in the seed migration script.

after some research, however, I found another interesting approach: bind an `after_create` event to the table, and [initialize the data](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-initialize-database-with-default-values-in) in the listener.
I haven't implemented this, so I'm not sure it can be done directly with TypeORM.

Comment: What about: https://github.com/w3tecch/typeorm-seeding#-introduction

Answer (score 67):

Unfortunately, there is no officially released solution from [TypeORM](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm) (at the time this answer was being published).

But there is a nice workaround we can use:

1. create another connection inside `ormconfig.js` file and specify another
   folder for "migrations" - in fact our **seeds**
2. generate and run your seeds with `-c <connection name>`. That's it!

Sample **ormconfig.js**:

```js
module.exports = [
  {
    ...,
    migrations: [
      'src/migrations/*.ts'
    ],
    cli: {
      migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'seed',
    ...,
    migrations: [
      'src/seeds/*.ts'
    ],
    cli: {
      migrationsDir: 'src/seeds',
    }
  }
]
```

Sample **package.json**:

```js
{
  ...
  scripts: {
    "seed:generate": "ts-node typeorm migration:generate -c seed -n ",
    "seed:run": "ts-node typeorm migration:run -c seed",
    "seed:revert": "ts-node typeorm migration:revert -c seed",
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 20):

For those who are using TypeORM with [Nest.js](https://github.com/nestjs), here is a solution to perform your seeding *programatically*, from within your code.

**Rough idea:**

- We create a dedicated "seeding module" containing a "seeding middleware" that is responsible for conducting the seeding and ensuring that all seeding is done before any request is answered.
- For any request that arrives, the seeding middleware intercepts it and postpones it until it is confirmed that seeding is done.
- If the db has been seeded, the "seeding middleware" passes the request to the next middleware.
- To speed things up, the "seeding middleware" keeps a "seeding complete" flag as state in memory to avoid any further db-checks after the seeding has occurred.

**Implementation:**

For this to work, first create a module that registers a middleware that listens to all incoming requests:

```ts
// file: src/seeding/SeedingModule.ts

@Module({})
export class SeedingModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(SeedingMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('*')
  }
}
```

Now create the middleware:

```ts
// file: src/seeding/SeedingMiddleware.ts
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { EntityManager } from 'typeorm';
import { SeedingLogEntry } from './entities/SeedingLogEntry.entity';

@Injectable()
export class SeedingMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {

  // to avoid roundtrips to db we store the info about whether
  // the seeding has been completed as boolean flag in the middleware
  // we use a promise to avoid concurrency cases. Concurrency cases may
  // occur if other requests also trigger a seeding while it has already
  // been started by the first request. The promise can be used by other
  // requests to wait for the seeding to finish.
  private isSeedingComplete: Promise<boolean>;

  constructor(
    private readonly entityManager: EntityManager,
  ) {}

  async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {

    if (await this.isSeedingComplete) {
      // seeding has already taken place,
      // we can short-circuit to the next middleware
      return next();
    }

    this.isSeedingComplete = (async () => {
      // for example you start with an initial seeding entry called 'initial-seeding'
      // on 2019-06-27. if 'initial-seeding' already exists in db, then this
      // part is skipped
      if (!await this.entityManager.findOne(SeedingLogEntry, { id: 'initial-seeding' })) {
        await this.entityManager.transaction(async transactionalEntityManager => {
          await transactionalEntityManager.save(User, initialUsers);
          await transactionalEntityManager.save(Role, initialRoles);
          // persist in db that 'initial-seeding' is complete
          await transactionalEntityManager.save(new SeedingLogEntry('initial-seeding'));
        });
      }

      // now a month later on 2019-07-25 you add another seeding
      // entry called 'another-seeding-round' since you want to initialize
      // entities that you just created a month later
      // since 'initial-seeding' already exists it is skipped but 'another-seeding-round'
      // will be executed now.
      if (!await this.entityManager.findOne(SeedingLogEntry, { id: 'another-seeding-round' })) {
        await this.entityManager.transaction(async transactionalEntityManager => {
          await transactionalEntityManager.save(MyNewEntity, initalSeedingForNewEntity);
          // persist in db that 'another-seeding-round' is complete
          await transactionalEntityManager.save(new SeedingLogEntry('another-seeding-round'));
        });
      }

      return true;
    })();

    await this.isSeedingComplete;

    next();
  }
}
```

Finally here is the entity that we use to record in our db that a seeding of a certain type has occured. Make sure to register it as entity in your `TypeOrmModule.forRoot` call.

```ts
// file: src/seeding/entities/Seeding.entity.ts

import { Entity, PrimaryColumn, CreateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Seeding {

  @PrimaryColumn()
  public id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  creationDate: Date;

  constructor(id?: string) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

**An alternative seeding solution using lifecycle events:**

with Nest.js, you can also implement the  `OnApplicationBootstrap` interface (see [lifecycle events](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events)) instead of going for a middleware-based solution to handle your seedings. The `onApplicationBootstrap` method will "called once the application has fully started and is bootstrapped". This approach, however, in contrast to a middleware-solution, will not allow you to seed your db in a multi-tenant environment where db-schemas for different tenants will be created at runtime and seeding needs to be conducted several times at runtime for different tenants after they are created.

Answer (score 6):

In Nest.js, this is what *B12Toaster*'s alternative solution using `OnApplicationBootstrap` could look like.

`src/seeding.service.ts`

```js
    import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { EntityManager } from 'typeorm';

    import { UserEntity} from 'src/entities/user.entity';
    import { RoleEntity } from 'src/entities/role.entity';

    import { userSeeds } from 'src/seeds/user.seeds';
    import { roleSeeds } from 'src/seeds/role.seeds';

    @Injectable()
    export class SeedingService {
      constructor(
        private readonly entityManager: EntityManager,
      ) {}

      async seed(): Promise<void> {

        // Replace with your own seeds
        await Promise.all([
          this.entityManager.save(UserEntity, userSeeds),
          this.entityManager.save(RoleEntity, roleSeeds),
        ]);

      }
    }
```

`src/app.module.ts`

```js
    import { Module, OnApplicationBootstrap } from '@nestjs/common'
    import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
    import { getConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';

    @Module({
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
          useFactory: async () =>
            Object.assign(await getConnectionOptions(), {
              autoLoadEntities: true,
            }),
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
          CompanyOrmEntity,
          ProductOrmEntity,
        ]),
      ],
      providers: [
        SeedingService,
        ...
      ],
      ...
    })
    export class AppModule implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
      constructor(
        private readonly seedingService: SeedingService,
      ) {}

      async onApplicationBootstrap(): Promise<void> {
        await this.seedingService.seed();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a module is being built for this, [typeorm-seeding](https://github.com/w3tecch/typeorm-seeding).
While using a initial migration for seeding also works its not very useful for testing where a freshly seeded DB may be needed for tests to pass. Once you start creating more migrations you can't drop, sync and run migrations without errors. This could be solved by being able to run `migration:run` for a single migration file but with the CLI you currently can't. My solution was a light weight script that accesses the QueryRunner object through a typeorm connection:

```
// testSeed.ts

import { ConnectionOptions, createConnection, QueryRunner } from "typeorm";

import { config } from "../config";

import { DevSeed } from "./DevSeed";

createConnection(config.typeOrmConfig as ConnectionOptions).then(async connection => {
    let queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner("master");

    // runs all seed SQL commands in this function.
    await DevSeed(queryRunner);

    await queryRunner.release();
    return connection.close();
});
```

Then run `node ./dist/path/to/testSeed.js`

Answer (score 2):

Also for NestJS you can use the [`nestjs-console`](https://github.com/Pop-Code/nestjs-console) package to execute tasks. This way you'll have access to entities, services, repositories, etc. I like this better than the middleware solution proposed by @B12Toaster because you don't need to maintain it as production code.

Create a `seed` command as shown below, then simply: `yarn console seed`.

There's a working example here (runs in the CI): https://github.com/thisismydesign/nestjs-starter/tree/ee7abf6d481b1420708e87dea3cb99ca110cc168

Along these lines:

`src/console.ts`

```js
import { BootstrapConsole } from 'nestjs-console';
import { AppModule } from 'src/server/app/app.module';

const bootstrap = new BootstrapConsole({
  module: AppModule,
  useDecorators: true,
});
bootstrap.init().then(async (app) => {
  try {
    await app.init();
    await bootstrap.boot();
    app.close();

    process.exit(0);
  } catch (e) {
    app.close();

    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

`src/console/seed.service.ts`

```js
import { Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Console, Command } from 'nestjs-console';
import { UsersService } from 'src/users/users.service';

@Console()
export class SeedService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(UsersService) private usersService: UsersService,
  ) {}

  @Command({
    command: 'seed',
    description: 'Seed DB',
  })
  async seed(): Promise<void> {
    await this.seedUsers();
  }

  async seedUsers() {
    await this.usersService.create({ name: 'Joe' });
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "console": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/console.ts",
```

Answer (score 2):

The **simplest** and most **efficient** way to do it is by creating a new migration file as **follows**:

```
    import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';
    
    export class <Class Name> implements MigrationInterface {

      public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {

        await queryRunner.connection
          .createQueryBuilder()
          .insert()
          .into('table_name', ['columns_1','column_2',...])
          .values([
            {
              columns_1: value,
             
            },
            {
              column_2: value
            }
          ])
          .execute();
      }
  }
```

Run the following code and it will work like a **charm**!

Answer (score 1):

I have modified @B12Toaster's answer (For seeding to the database in NestJs) to be able to take an array of objects to seed. His answer helped considerably and I was also looking for a way to make it take many DB objects at once. Here's the little modification made to the seedingMiddleware.ts

```
// file: src/seeding/SeedingMiddleware.ts

import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { TxnCategory } from 'src/txn-categories/entities/txn-category.entity';
import { init_categories } from 'src/txn-categories/entities/txn_cat-seed-data';
import { init_services } from 'src/txn-services/entities/txn-serv-seed-data';
import { TxnService } from 'src/txn-services/entities/txn-service.entity';
import { EntityManager } from 'typeorm';
import { Seeding } from './entities/seeding.entity';

@Injectable()
export class SeedingMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  // to avoid roundtrips to db we store the info about whether
  // the seeding has been completed as boolean flag in the middleware
  // we use a promise to avoid concurrency cases. Concurrency cases may
  // occur if other requests also trigger a seeding while it has already
  // been started by the first request. The promise can be used by other
  // requests to wait for the seeding to finish.
  private isSeedingComplete: Promise<boolean>;

  constructor(private readonly entityManager: EntityManager) {}

  async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: any) {
    if (await this.isSeedingComplete) {
      // seeding has already taken place,
      // we can short-circuit to the next middleware
      return next();
    }

    this.isSeedingComplete = (async () => {
      // for example you start with an initial seeding entry called 'initial-seeding'
      // if 'init-txn-cats' and 'init-txn-serv' already exists in db, then this
      // part is skipped
  
      // MODIFIED
      if (
        !(await this.entityManager.findOne(Seeding, {
          id: 'init-txn-cats',
        }))
      ) {
        await this.entityManager.transaction(
          async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < init_categories.length; i++) {
              await transactionalEntityManager.save(
                TxnCategory,
                init_categories[i],
              );
            }
            await transactionalEntityManager.save(new Seeding('init-txn-cats'));
          },
        );
      }

      // MODIFIED
      if (
        !(await this.entityManager.findOne(Seeding, {
          id: 'init-txn-serv',
        }))
      ) {
        await this.entityManager.transaction(
          async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < init_services.length; i++) {
              await transactionalEntityManager.save(
                TxnService,
                init_services[i],
              );
            }
            await transactionalEntityManager.save(new Seeding('init-txn-serv'));
          },
        );
      }

      return true;
    })();

    await this.isSeedingComplete;
    next();
  }
}
```

Then the array of DB objects referenced would be like so:

```
// file: src/txn-categories/entities/txn_cat-seed-data.ts

export const init_categories = [
  {
    id: 1,
    category_name: 'name 1',
    category_code: 'cat_code_1',
    enabled: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    category_name: 'name 2',
    category_code: 'cat_code_2',
    enabled: true,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    category_name: 'name 3',
    category_code: 'cat_code_3',
    enabled: true,
  },

// etc
];
```

Same format for the src/txn-services/entities/txn-serv-seed-data.ts file.

Every other thing in B12Toaster's answer remains the same hence you'll still have your module and entity files as below:

SeedingModule:

```
// file: src/seeding/SeedingModule.ts

@Module({})
export class SeedingModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(SeedingMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('*')
  }
}
```

SeedingEntity:

```
// file: src/seeding/entities/Seeding.entity.ts

import { Entity, PrimaryColumn, CreateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Seeding {

  @PrimaryColumn()
  public id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  creationDate: Date;

  constructor(id?: string) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

so heres how I am seeding data from an sql file with insert statement.
Heres my whole migration file after adding the seed

```js
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';

let insertPermissionQueries = fs
    .readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../scripts/sql/insert.sql'))
    .toString()
    .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ' ') // remove newlines
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' '); // excess white space

export class init1591103087130 implements MigrationInterface {
    name = 'init1591103087130';

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(
            `CREATE TABLE "public"."RoleTemp" ("idx" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "name" text, "created_on" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(), "is_active" boolean DEFAULT true, "role_type" text, "created_by" uuid NOT NULL, "status" text, "alias" text, "operation" text, "rejection_reason" text, "id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "is_obsolete" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false, "modified_on" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "role_id" integer, CONSTRAINT "UQ_835baad60041a3413f9ef95bc07" UNIQUE ("idx"), CONSTRAINT "PK_a76dd0012be252eefbdd4a2a589" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "RoleTemp_idx_key" ON "public"."RoleTemp" ("idx") `,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `CREATE TABLE "public"."PermissionRoleTemp" ("idx" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "created_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "permission_base_name" text, "id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "is_obsolete" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false, "modified_on" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "role_id" integer NOT NULL, "permission_id" integer NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "PK_c1f2648a18ac911e096f08c187d" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `CREATE TABLE "public"."Permission" ("idx" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "base_name" text NOT NULL, "url" text NOT NULL, "method" text NOT NULL, "created_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "is_active" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true, "permission_type" text, "alias" text NOT NULL, "id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "is_obsolete" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false, "modified_on" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CONSTRAINT "PK_28657fa560adca66b359c18b952" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `CREATE TABLE "public"."PermissionRole" ("idx" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "created_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "is_active" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true, "permission_base_name" text NOT NULL, "id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "is_obsolete" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false, "modified_on" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "role_id" integer NOT NULL, "permission_id" integer NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "PK_b5e2271c229f65f17ee93677a0f" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `CREATE TABLE "public"."UserRole" ("idx" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "created_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "is_active" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true, "id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "is_obsolete" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false, "modified_on" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "role_id" integer NOT NULL, "company_user_id" integer NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "PK_431fc1ec3d46ac513ef3701604e" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `CREATE TABLE "public"."UsersTemp" ("idx" uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1(), "username" text, "first_name" text, "middle_name" text, "last_name" text, "password" text, "email" text, "address" text, "phone_number" text, "phone_ext" text, "company_idx" uuid, "is_superadmin" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false, "operation" text, "created_by" text, "status" text, "rejection_reason" text, "created_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "is_active" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true, "id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "is_obsolete" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false, "modified_on" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "role_id" integer, "user_id" integer, CONSTRAINT "PK_9d3fbcec3cc0b054324f93da038" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `CREATE TABLE "public"."Role" ("idx" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "name" text NOT NULL, "alias" text NOT NULL, "created_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "is_active" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true, "role_type" text, "created_by" uuid NOT NULL, "id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "is_obsolete" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false, "modified_on" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CONSTRAINT "UQ_c9a53325a7642edb5f9bd44f5aa" UNIQUE ("idx"), CONSTRAINT "PK_422113329ddec949e76c7943c56" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "Role_idx_key" ON "public"."Role" ("idx") `,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `CREATE TABLE "public"."Users" ("idx" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "username" text NOT NULL, "first_name" text NOT NULL, "middle_name" text, "last_name" text NOT NULL, "password" text NOT NULL, "email" text, "address" text, "phone_number" text, "phone_ext" text, "company_idx" uuid, "created_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "is_active" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true, "is_superadmin" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false, "id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "is_obsolete" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false, "modified_on" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "role_id" integer NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "PK_ac3c96e3c912cbda773b7c7edc9" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `CREATE TABLE "public"."CompanyUser" ("id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "is_obsolete" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false, "modified_on" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "idx" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "company_idx" uuid, "created_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "is_active" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true, "user_id" integer, CONSTRAINT "PK_4a915d69bf079a8e5dd10784cc3" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."RoleTemp" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_d304588d17c9349ca6e7ebee5d3" FOREIGN KEY ("role_id") REFERENCES "public"."Role"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."PermissionRoleTemp" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_7e7cdde853500f56b3db43fc258" FOREIGN KEY ("role_id") REFERENCES "public"."RoleTemp"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."PermissionRoleTemp" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_0068d3de1c59050561d35f17544" FOREIGN KEY ("permission_id") REFERENCES "public"."Permission"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."PermissionRole" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_5b57492441a568bc7562fbbaa5b" FOREIGN KEY ("role_id") REFERENCES "public"."Role"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."PermissionRole" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_1951a810af06342fcd4530ec61c" FOREIGN KEY ("permission_id") REFERENCES "public"."Permission"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."UserRole" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_fb09d73b0dd011be81a272e1efa" FOREIGN KEY ("role_id") REFERENCES "public"."Role"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."UserRole" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_b221977a41587e58d7c58e16db0" FOREIGN KEY ("company_user_id") REFERENCES "public"."CompanyUser"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."UsersTemp" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_6d74dfaddaa94e1bba0c8c12a2f" FOREIGN KEY ("role_id") REFERENCES "public"."Role"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."UsersTemp" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_e5b2930fe35042dab17945bb131" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "public"."Users"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."Users" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_34be125e29cee0e71d58456aed7" FOREIGN KEY ("role_id") REFERENCES "public"."Role"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."CompanyUser" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_1354e3e408b5ffdebe476a6fbd2" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "public"."Users"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(insertPermissionQueries);
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."CompanyUser" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_1354e3e408b5ffdebe476a6fbd2"`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."Users" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_34be125e29cee0e71d58456aed7"`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."UsersTemp" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_e5b2930fe35042dab17945bb131"`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."UsersTemp" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_6d74dfaddaa94e1bba0c8c12a2f"`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."UserRole" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_b221977a41587e58d7c58e16db0"`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."UserRole" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_fb09d73b0dd011be81a272e1efa"`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."PermissionRole" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_1951a810af06342fcd4530ec61c"`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."PermissionRole" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_5b57492441a568bc7562fbbaa5b"`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."PermissionRoleTemp" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_0068d3de1c59050561d35f17544"`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."PermissionRoleTemp" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_7e7cdde853500f56b3db43fc258"`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "public"."RoleTemp" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_d304588d17c9349ca6e7ebee5d3"`,
        );
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "public"."CompanyUser"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "public"."Users"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP INDEX "public"."Role_idx_key"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "public"."Role"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "public"."UsersTemp"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "public"."UserRole"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "public"."PermissionRole"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "public"."Permission"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "public"."PermissionRoleTemp"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP INDEX "public"."RoleTemp_idx_key"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "public"."RoleTemp"`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a simpler method with migrations here is my code i believe it should be simpler so run this in your migrations

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';
const tableName = 'foo';
const columnName = 'foo_column';
const features = ['foo_content_1', 'foo_content_2'];

export class seedIntoPermissionsTable1638518166717 implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await Promise.all(features.map((feature) => queryRunner.query(`INSERT INTO ${tableName} (${columnName}) VALUES ('${feature}')`)));
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await Promise.all(features.map((feature) => queryRunner.query(`DELETE FROM ${tableName} WHERE ${columnName}='${feature}';`)));
  }
}
```

This is what i tend to use for my seeders.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple script to make a post on the endpoint I need. For small projects and studies I think it is simpler than doing the other options.

I got the curl command from Postman, then the script was practically just creating the test payload.

Below is an example.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

DATA=""

CreateAccount() {
    curl --location 'http://localhost:3000/v1/accounts' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data "$1"
    echo
}
CreateMovement() {
    curl --location 'http://localhost:3000/v1/movements' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data "$1"
    echo
}

CreateAccount '{ "name": "First Account Name", "type": 1 }'
CreateAccount '{ "name": "Second account", "type": 2 }'

CreateMovement '{ "destiny": 1, value: 10 }
CreateMovement '{ "destiny": 2, value: 10 }
CreateMovement '{ "origin": 1, "destiny": 2, value: 2 }
```