# TypeORM-seeding runs through but no new entries are added

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm, seeding

I am trying to add some data to my database using typeorm-seeding. Running `seed:run` goes through and says that it executes my seeds, however, no new entries in the DB are added. The paths to my seeds are correct, any suggestions what could be wrong ? :)
I have the following basic `.env` file

```yaml
# Database Config
IDEA_DB_HOST=localhost
IDEA_DB_PORT=5432
IDEA_DB_USER=postgres
IDEA_DB_PASS=postgres
IDEA_DB_NAME=idea_db
```

and the following `ormconfig.js`

```js
const path = require('path'); // eslint-disable-line

module.exports = {
  host: process.env.IDEA_DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.IDEA_DB_USER,
  password: process.env.IDEA_DB_PASS,
  port: process.env.IDEA_DB_PORT,
  name: process.env.IDEA_DB_NAME,
  seeds: ['src/database/seeds/*.ts'],
  factories: ['src/database/factories/*.ts'],
  type: 'postgres',
  entities: ['src/**/entities/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: true,
  logging: false,
};
```

My seed is very basic

```js
import { Factory, Seeder } from 'typeorm-seeding';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import {
  Exercise,
  ExerciseType,
} from '../../exercises/entities/exercise.entity';

export default class CreateExercises implements Seeder {
  public async run(factory: Factory, connection: Connection): Promise<any> {
    await connection
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .insert()
      .into(Exercise)
      .values([
        {
          id: 1,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          updatedAt: new Date(),
          content: 'some demo content',
          solution: 'some demo content',
          labels: ['Winter'],
          exerciseType: ExerciseType.MATHE,
          skills: ['skill 1'],
          minDifficulty: 1,
          maxDifficulty: 2,
          verified: true,
          authorId: '65ca2dd2-6649-11ec-90d6-0242ac120003',
        },
      ])
      .execute();
  }
}
```

And I get the following output when I run seed:run

```
$ ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm-seeding/dist/cli.js seed
  TypeORM Seeding v1.6.1
√ ORM Config loaded
√ Factories are imported
√ Seeders are imported
√ Database connected
√ Seeder CreateExercises executed
  Finished Seeding
Done in 4.58s.
```

Comment: Hi, did you found any reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the columns names after the table.

I did for example so here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/typeOrm-seeding-solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51198817/typeorm-how-to-seed-database/75383155#75383155)

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are not save data !

my opinion is to work like this

```
import { Factory, Seeder } from 'typeorm-seeding';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import {
  Exercise,
  ExerciseType,
} from '../../exercises/entities/exercise.entity';

export default class CreateExercises implements Seeder {
  private data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date(),
      content: 'some demo content',
      solution: 'some demo content',
      labels: ['Winter'],
      exerciseType: ExerciseType.MATHE,
      skills: ['skill 1'],
      minDifficulty: 1,
      maxDifficulty: 2,
      verified: true,
      authorId: '65ca2dd2-6649-11ec-90d6-0242ac120003',
    },
  ];
  public async run(factory: Factory, connection: Connection): Promise<any> {
    await Promise.all(
      this.data.map((x) =>
        connection.getRepository<Exercise>('exercise').create(x).save(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems to not work, first of all the syntax `create(x).save()` seems to not work, I tried to do it with just `save(x)`, but it didnt work either

Comment: what is wrong ?